# @ModelAttribute ignore some fields

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a User class with lombok notations

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
class User { 
    String name,
    String age,
    String city
}
```

and post endpoint with following function type

```
search(@ModelAttribute User user)
```

I want to get only name and age fields from query params and ignore city parameter. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I would create another Object for example `InUser` which hold only the necessary attributes :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
class InUser { 
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

then instead call :

```
search(@ModelAttribute InUser user)
```

And in your controller you can call a mapper to create a new `User` object based in `InUser`